# Why does my parbox not work in latex table cell

Tags: latex

In my simple mwe of a Gantt chart below, using parbox (commented out in the code below) gives error "! Missing number, treated as zero.\c@ }"
I am wondering if there is a package I am not loading or some other problem with my code.
I will appreciate help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{boldline,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{4.4cm}V{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}}
\hline
\raggedleft Months
&
\multicolumn{4}{V{2.5}cV{2.5}}{1} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{2} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{3} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{4} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{5} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{6}
\\ \hline
%\parbox{.99\linewidth}{
%\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label=\alph*), leftmargin=*]
%\item First programme execution 
%\item First program completion
%\end{enumerate}
%}
& \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
%\parbox{.99\linewidth}{
%\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label=\alph*), leftmargin=*]
%\item second programme execution 
%\item second program completion
%\end{enumerate}
%}
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with tables or parboxes, the problem is the content of your parbox

```
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label=\alph*), leftmargin=*]
\item First programme execution 
\item First program completion
\end{enumerate}
```

is not default latex syntax. All these optional arguments for the `enumerate` environment come from the `enumitem` package which is missing in your preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{boldline,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{4.4cm}V{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}ccccV{2.5}}
\hline
\raggedleft Months
&
\multicolumn{4}{V{2.5}cV{2.5}}{1} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{2} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{3} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{4} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{5} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{2.5}}{6}
\\ \hline
\parbox{.99\linewidth}{
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label=\alph*), leftmargin=*]
\item First programme execution 
\item First program completion
\end{enumerate}
}
& \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} & \cellcolor{blue!100} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\parbox{.99\linewidth}{
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, label=\alph*), leftmargin=*]
\item second programme execution 
\item second program completion
\end{enumerate}
}
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100} & \cellcolor{green!100}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I never thought of enumitem